# Glide isn't displaying images in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-glide

In my app I have the following code in my `captureBonus` activity (which is where the `ImageView` lives as well):

```
// Process the Sample Image
bonusSampleImage = findViewById(R.id.bonusSampleImage);
Glide.with(this)
    .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
    //.load("https://www.tourofhonor.com/appimages/2019fl4.jpg")
    .into(bonusSampleImage);
```

But when I run my app I'm not getting any image view at all. Before I added the above code, the image view with its placeholder would appear. Also, I tried both links in the code, neither work (I thought it was https related).

I have the internet and external storage permissions already.

I found that Glide had logged some activity in logcat, it was only viewable in verbose mode though:

```
2019-05-01 16:51:38.329 3182-3182/net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
2019-05-01 16:51:38.568 3182-3182/net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor I/ViewTarget: Glide treats LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT as a request for an image the size of this device's screen dimensions. If you want to load the original image and are ok with the corresponding memory cost and OOMs (depending on the input size), use .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL). Otherwise, use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, set layout_width and layout_height to fixed dimension, or use .override() with fixed dimensions.
2019-05-01 16:51:38.690 3182-3182/net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor W/Glide: Load failed for http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png with size [1032x2038]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "i.imgur.com": No address associated with hostname)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "i.imgur.com": No address associated with hostname)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "i.imgur.com": No address associated with hostname)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "i.imgur.com": No address associated with hostname
2019-05-01 16:51:38.690 3182-3182/net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
```

Here is the corresponding layout XML for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".captureBonus">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/basicBonusInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusName"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/valueCategory"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusName"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusCode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusCode"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusName"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bonusLocationInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/basicBonusInfo">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusAddress"
                android:text="1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusCity"
                android:text="Washington"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusAddress"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusState"
                android:text="DC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusAddress"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusCity"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusGPSLabel"
                android:text="GPS:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusCity"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusGPSCoordinates"
                android:text="XX.YYYYYY, -XX.YYYYYY"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/bonusCity"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bonusMainImage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mainImageDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bonusLocationInfo"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image_taken"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bonusSecondaryImage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/secondaryImageDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bonusMainImage"
            android:src="@drawable/optional_2nd_image"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additionalBonusDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblSampleBonusImage"
            android:layout_below="@id/bonusSecondaryImage"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bonusSampleImage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/sampleImageDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/additionalBonusDetails"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_image_missing"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusFlavorLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bonus Notes"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/bonusSampleImage"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusFlavorContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/bonusFlavorLabel"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmitBonus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btnLblSubmitBonus"
            android:layout_below="@id/bonusFlavorContent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is the device version are you running this on? If using Android 9 you will need a network security config added to your app see - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: Umm, in my app file I have `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 28`. My actual test device is ruining Android 8.0.0

Comment: What does your logcat say? Please check for anything unusual that is appearing in your logcat and post it here.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I didn't see any error, but there were some messages in Verbose. I have added them to my original question.

Comment: I think I understood the problem. Please post the layout of your `ImageView`.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have added the layout XML

Comment: Have you tried a different image URL not from Imgur?

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio Yes, the other URL in the sample code (https://www.tourofhonor.com/appimages/2019fl4.jpg). In the logcat I get the same errors though, just using this URL instead of the Imgur one.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that works. It works fine in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `s` in your URL. Please use `https` instead of `http` for the image URL.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load("https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")  // Add https instead of http
    .placeholder(R.drawable.sample_image_missing)  // Add a placeholder here
    .into(bonusSampleImage);
```

And the following in your dependency in your `build.gradle` file. I think this one is missing.

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

As stated in the [Glide's](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) documentation you need have the repositories as well if you do not have those already.

And yes, please check your internet connection as well.

Comment: I have the dependencies, but not the repositories, do I need that section as well in my Gradle? I'm not using Maven that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the repositories as well. And fix the URL please.

Comment: I have added the s and added the repositories, and it still doesn't work. It did get rid of the first line of the logcat message, but it looks like it is trying to find a screen sized file (1032x2038). My test image on Imgur is 400x486, and the actual image to be used on my tourofhonor.com domain is 400x300. All the tutorials I can find regarding Glide has their XML setup similar to mine (match_parent for width, and wrap_content for height), so not sure why it is complaining.

Comment: Let me check your whole layout.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you please add a `placeholder` while setting up your Glide and then let me know if that works? I have checked it in my device using your full layout. There's nothing wrong except this one.

Comment: And yes, do not forget to add `https` in the image URL. For me, it did not work for this error for the first time.

Comment: I tried it again using `.load("https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")` and adding the placeholder. The placeholder does appear now, but I still get the same messages in the logcat and the linked image isn't appearing.

Comment: I think the last problem that you might have is with your internet connection. Please check the internet connection again in your device or emulator. And yes, I have uploaded my code in the Github here - https://github.com/masudias/so-playground. You might fork and run the code to check if there is anything different here. It's working in my side.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Turns out the device wasn't online as I moved recently and forgot to add it to the WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}

repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
```

Create a class MyGlideApp and rebuild your project.

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideApp extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Paste this in your activity class

```
public void loadGlideImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, String url) {
            GlideApp.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .signature(new ObjectKey(url))
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .into(imageView);
    }
```

Then you can do

```
String img_url = "https://www.tourofhonor.com/appimages/2019fl4.jpg";
loadGlideImage(this, bonusSampleImage, img_url);
```

Comment: I get "cannot resolve symbol GlideApp" when I copy paste that function into my activity.

Comment: I have done all of that and I still get "cannot resolve symbol GlideApp" when I copy paste the function over. If I change `GlideApp` to `myGlideApp` or `GlideModule`, then it complains about the with saying it cannot resolve method.

Comment: Have rebuilt your project?